# how to copy part of char buffer to std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdlist

I try to store instances of class `Person` in std::list `Users`. Before putting each instance to `Users` I want to copy first 10 bytes from `buf` to std::string `Name`. How can I do that?

```
class Person {
  public:   
   Person(){ std::cout << "Constructing Person " << std::endl;}
  private:
   std::string Name;
};

int main() {

  unsigned char buf[1024];
  std::list<Person> Users;

  Person ps;
  Users.push_back(ps);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean take the first 10 bytes, create a Person with string, and advance to take the next 10 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your constructor for doing this:

```
class Person {
  public:   
   Person(const char* buf_, size_type size_) 
   : name(buf_,size_) { 
       std::cout << "Constructing Person " << std::endl;
   }
   // ....
};
```

and in `main()` write

```
Person ps(buf,10);
```

Comment: @Columbo I'm not debating good or bad in my statement, I'm simply providing an answer to your question. However if you want to get argumentative about it you're solution is not without issue. I'm sure you'll spot it eventually.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious If there is an issue with my answer feel free to comment on it. Anyway, the whole solution with taking a `char const*` is suboptimal as it can force unnecessary copies. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Columbo I see no unnecessary copies with that constructor and you're going to have a very difficult time showing that there are.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious `std::string str`. Now, construct a `Person` with `Name` equal to `str`.

Comment: @Columbo that's not what the OP is doing.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It doesn't matter. We want to provide general solutions on SO.

Comment: Could you guys please go and discuss that on chat?!?

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an appropriate constructor for `Person`.

```
Person(std::string Name) : Name(std::move(Name)) {}
```

Definition of a `Person` would be

```
Person ps(std::string(buf, 10));
```

Or write directly:

```
Users.emplace_back( std::string(buf, 10) );
```

Comment: In this case the constructor for `Person` should really be declared `explicit`. Allowing implicit conversions between dissimilar types is bad form and can easily lead to incorrect code and code that is unclear. your last snippet of code is a good example of the latter. Anyone looking at that code could assume `User` is a container of strings not `Person`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The last line will work with the constructor being explicit. Can you see why? PS: Look at the definition of `emplace_back` and `allocator<>::construct`. And either way, this is just an example and not normative.